# clisp converting between infix, postfix, prefix (i'm trying if statements)

Tags: if-statement, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm using CLISP and am trying

```
(if ( = (first '(+ 2 3)) + ) 10 20) //10 and 20 are just placeholders
```

I am trying to create a program that converts between infix, postfix, and prefix. I believe that my first step should be finding the symbols +, -, *, and / in the string. There will be no parentheses in the input. So, i am trying to search for each symbol systematically. the advantage of my approach is the ability to prioritize * over + etc.

I have a general idea of my approach, but any thoughts would be nice.
my first idea is:

```
(append (rest '(+ 2 3)) (list (first '(+ 2 3))))
```

and yes, i plan on using recursion.

Comment: i have solved my own question. using "eq" instead of "=" helped.

Comment: I recommend you post your answer and mark as accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some more googling brought me to [What's the difference between eq, eql, equal, and equalp in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-lisp) so i decided to implement "eq" instead of "=" and it worked just as expected.

Comment: Typically, you want to use EQL instead of EQ, except for the (very few) cases where you actually want to use EQ.