# remove duplicated lists inside list in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How do i remove duplicated lists inside a list in common-lisp?
I tried this:

```
(remove-duplicates '( (1 2 3) (1 2 3)))
```

But it evaluates to  `((1 2 3) (1 2 3))`, not `((1 2 3))`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the keyword argument `:test` to specify the function that defines whether or not two items are duplicates of each other. Most lisp functions, including `remove-duplicates`, use `eql` to test for equality by default. `eql` is much stricter than `equal`, which is what you probably want to be using.

```
 (remove-duplicates '((1 2 3) (1 2 3)) :test #'equal)
```

This evaluates to `'((1 2 3))`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/547436/1530508) for more detail about the difference between `eql` and `equal`.

Comment: That's not the "second optional argument";  `test` is a keyword argument.  The order of the keyword arguments doesn't matter.  E.g., you could do `(remove-duplicates list :test 'equal :from-end t)` or `(remove-duplicates list :from-end t :test 'equal)` and the results would be the same.  Optional arguments in Common Lisp are _position_ based, but keyword arguments are not.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Good point. Editing.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(remove-duplicates '((1 2 3) (1 2 3)) :test #'equal)
```