# LISP: Removing elements from list already existing in another

Tags: list, duplicates, lisp, project, remove-if

Can anybody explain to me why this:

```
(remove-if #'(lambda (var) (member var (list "x"))) (list "x" "y" "z"))
```

returns this:

```
("x" "y" "z")
```

but this:

```
(remove-if #'(lambda (var) (member var (list 1))) (list 1 2 4))
```

returns this:

```
(2 4)
```

?

Answer (score 4):

## The Answer

Pass `:test #'equal` to [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm):

```
(remove-if #'(lambda (var) (member var (list "x") :test #'equal)) (list "x" "y" "z"))
==> ("y" "z")
```

Note that

```
(eql "x" "x")
==> NIL
(equal "x" "x")
==> T
(eql 1 1)
==> T
```

## The Reason

The default [One-Argument Test in Common Lisp is `eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_bb.htm).

It is the most reasonable choice between the 4(!) general purpose comparison functions provided for by the ANSI CL standard:

- [`eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) is too implementation-dependent and does not work as one probably wants on numbers and characters
- [`equal`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm) and [`equalp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equalp.htm) traverse objects and thus take a long time for huge ones and may never terminate for circular ones.

See also [the difference between `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, and `equalp` in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp).

## The Right Way

Use [`set-difference`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_di.htm) instead of `remove-if` + `member`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) still kind of a newb at this, and my mindset is still too much linked to C&C++

Comment: @MiguelNoronha: if your question has been answered, should should close it by [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)