# Comparing a number and a list object in lisp

Tags: lisp

I am new to lisp so I apologize if advance it this is a simple question.

I have a list:

```
(set ‘inventory ‘(parts
                   ((item 1001) (shoes (color brown) (size 10) (cost 20))) 
                   ((item 2011) (skirt (color blue) (size 4) (cost 10)))
                   ((item 2120) (pants (color white) (size 32) (cost 30)))
                   ((item 2121) (pants (color brown) (size 34) (cost 30)))))
```

I am trying to write a function that looks through the list by item number and return the correct one.

`(findItem 1001 inventory)` should return:

```
((item 1001) (shoes (color brown) (size 10) (cost 20)))
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(defun findItem (q i)   
    (cond
        ((null q)
         nil)
        ((null (cdr i))
         nil)
        ((eq `parts (car i))
         (findItem q (cdr i)))
        ((eq q (cdr (car (car i))))
         (car i))
        (T
         (findItem q (cdr i)))))
```

Everything seems to work except `((eq q (cdr (car (car i)))) (car i))`

`(cdr (car (car i)))` should return (1001) or the part number

But the eq does not evaluate to true so the function overall returns nil.

And help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between eq, eql, equal, and equalp in Common Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(cdr (car (car '((item 1001) (shoes (color brown) (size 10) (cost 20))))))
```

Doesn't work since `caar` is `item` and you cannot take the `cdr` of a symbol. 
You should play with it like this before you get it right:

```
(defparameter *item*  '((item 1001) (shoes (color brown) (size 10) (cost 20))))
(car *item*) ; ==> (item 1001)
(caar *item*) ; ==> item
(cdar *item*) ; ==> (1001)
```

Now `c<runs of a and d>r` is an abbriviation for nested `car` and `cdr` eg `(car (cdr (cdr x)))` (also known as `third`) can be abbriviated `caddr` when reading the as and ds from right to left you see why.

Numbers are not guaranteed to be `eq` even when they represent the same value. Tou can use `equal` to get a true value when two values look alike and there are `=` which only works for numbers that might be faster in some implementations.

`set` is deprecated. For making global variables use `defparameter` and use `*earmuffs*` to indicate that they are global variables.

I urge you to chose sensible names as `q` and `i` doesn't really mean anything. Also using [CL coding conversion](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt) make your code concise and readable by other lispers. Eg:

```
(defun find-item (item-number inventory)
  "Finds the record in inventory that has a specific item number"
  (cond ((endp inventory) nil)
        ...))
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [What's the difference between eq, eql, equal, and equalp in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/547436/850781), using
[`eq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq.htm) to compare
[`cons`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_cons.htm) cells is wrong. 
You should either use [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) or extract
the number, i.e., replace `(cdr (car (car i)))` with
[`cadaar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm) so that 
you will get `1001` instead of `(1001)`.

Also, [`set`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set.htm) is deprecated, use
[`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm) or
[`defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) instead.

Also, you can use built-in
[`find`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_.htm) instead:

```
(find 1001 (cdr inventory) :key #'cadar)
==> ((ITEM 1001) (SHOES (COLOR BROWN) (SIZE 10) (COST 20)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35852795/124319), let me address some stylistic issues. Like in any other language, you should try to design your code to define a sensible interface.

I could tell you that you might prefer to use structures or objects, but I actually think that the use of lists is not necessarily bad. What bothers me is the explicit use of `CADAR` or `CDR`: you are making assumptions about your code which introduces coupling for no particular reason. A first step to separate abstraction from implementation is to define accessor functions, like `item-reference`, `row-reference` (for each entry), and so on.

If you happen to reorganize your data, you will be happy to know that you only need to change the one place where you define `(item-reference x)` to be `(CAADDR x)` (for example).

By the way, Common Lisp [structures](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/m_defstr.htm) can be implemented on top of lists if you provide both `:named` and a `:type list` argument. For example, you can define an `item` structure as follows:

```
> (defstruct (item (:type list) :named) reference)
```

Then, the following actually build a list where the first element indicates the type:

```
> (make-item :reference 300)
=> (ITEM 300)
```

The `defstruct` also creates accessors:

```
> (item-reference *)
300

> (setf (item-reference **) 1010)
1010
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is an [alist](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-lists-other-uses-for-cons-cells.html). You should leverage the existing functions that are [built in](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) for working with this data structure.

```
(defun find-item (num list)
  (assoc num (cdr list) 
         :test (lambda (num b)
                 (equal num (second b)))))
```

Note that I have also changed the name of your function to be more in keeping with list style.