# comparing quoted lists return nil, why?

Tags: common-lisp

I am learning common lisp.

It's not explained anywhere but I tried:

```
(eq '(a b c) '(a b c))
```

which evaluates to NIL.

Why returning Nil from lisp's perspective? I am interested to know how it evaluates to Nil in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: *"It's not explained anywhere"* :-D. Please have look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp

Comment: Generally it is undefined if that expression returns NIL or T in a Common Lisp program. So don't get too excited that in your case you got NIL as a result.

Comment: your link said (eq '(a . b) '(a . b)) might be true or false.  why?

Comment: thanks @Rainer Joswig.