# LISP - sequence of integers

Tags: list, lisp

Does exist a function in LISP for making a sequence of integers like `(0 1 2 3)`?

I found `make-sequence`, but I didn't find out how to make a sequence of integers.

I tried `make-list` and nothing.

I know that in Scheme exists `(build-list 5 (lambda (x) x))`. I tried to change the `build-list` with `make-list`, but it didn't work.

Some ideas? Thanks

Edit: I need something like `make-list 5 ==> (0 1 2 3 4)`

Comment: What lisp are you using?  I seem to remember from the old days that (list 1 2 3) would do it.

Comment: @IanA.Mason Common Lisp (IDE Lisp Works). I can do `(list 1 2 3)` ,because I know only the length of the list . I need something like `make-list 5 ==> (0 1 2 3 4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply done with `loop`:

```
(loop :for n :below 10 :collect n)        
; ==> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: `(loop for n below 10 collect n)`

Comment: I built my own function:
`(defun build-sequence (length)
  (let ((seq '()))
    (dotimes (i length)
    (setq seq (cons i seq)))
    (reverse seq)))`

Comment: @Kaz I knew there were something like that but somehow I didn't remember :-) Updated.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu FYI, you implemented the well-known push/nreverse idiom (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html)

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu  `(setq seq (cons i seq))` is what `(push i seq)` does. Moreover, `push` avoids evaluating `seq` twice.  Usually we use `nreverse` to reverse a list that we just constructed ourselves,  before returning it to the caller. `reverse` wastefully allocates a whole new list.

Comment: There is no need to use keywords in `loop`; they only add keystrokes and noise. The designers of `loop` went out of the way to make it unnecessary to ever use package prefixes on the clause keywords by essentially treating them as strings: `:collect`, `cl-user:collect`, `mypackage:collect` are all equivalent.

Comment: @Kaz It's a matter of opinion. How I see using keywords makes them different than the expressions, which might be symbols as well. I prefer readability before redundant keystrokes. Also without you get the symbols in the current package.

Comment: @Kaz How does `push` avoid evaluating `seq` twice? `(macroexpand '(push i seq)) ; ==> (setq seq (cons i seq))`. Seems to be its the exact same thing with fewer keypresses.

Comment: @Kaz @Sylwester I think that `(setq seq (cons i seq))` does NOT evaluate "seq" twice! It evaluates once "i" and once "seq", calls "cons" and puts the result into the cell-value of the symbol whose name is "seq".  When you use `(setq seq (cons i seq))` instead of `(push i seq)`, the _reader_ (the "read" function) is called twice to resolve the "seq" string into the symbol whose name is "seq" (in the current package).

Comment: @duthen The expression contains two occurrences of `seq`; how can it not evaluate it twice? What if we replace `seq` with `(aref (cdr x) y)`? Do you believe that `(setq (aref (cdr x) y) (cons i (aref (cdr x) y)))` doesn't evaluate `x` and `y` and `(cdr x)` twice, and doesn' t index into the array twice?

Comment: @duthen My point was that  since `push` is a macro it gets expanded into `(setq seq (cons i seq))` before compilation. Thus its only a less typing matter and nothing to do with evaluation since the compiler will be compiling `(setq seq (cons i seq))`  in both cases with the exact same result.

Comment: @Sylwester Expressions denoting places can contain subexpressions, and those have to be evaluated in order to access the place or store a value into it. An ANSI-CL-conforming `(push val place)` has to expand in such a way that if the evaluation of `place` produces side effects, those side effects happen only once.

Comment: @Kaz True, but then instead of just `seq` you would have had a slightly more complex expression like `(push 1 (caddr x))` which would indeed turn into a `let*` chain to ensure only one evaluation. In the code above `seq` is a binding and thus it does not suffer from being evaluated more than once and the expansion reflects that.

Comment: @Kaz I'm sorry but the expression is `(setq seq (cons i seq))` but not `(setf seq (cons i seq))`, which is a little bit different. The expression you wrote `(setq (aref (cdr x) y) (cons i (aref (cdr x) y)))` will produce an error, because the first argument is not a variable. The trailing "q" in "setq" stands for "quote" and means that it does NOT evaluate its first argument. Hence "setq" is not like a normal function which evaluates all its arguments.

Comment: @duthen `(setq x y)` and `(setf x y)` are equivalent in Common Lisp if the `x` expression is a symbol. If it isn't a symbol, then the `setq` is erroneous. Hence, `setq` can always be replaced by `setf`, but not *vice versa*. Interestingly, under the `setq`, `x` may be a symbol macro which expands to a compound expression. E.g. `(symbol-macrolet ((x (slot-value obj 'slot))) (setq x 42))` will store 42 into `(slot-value obj 'slot)` even though `(setq (slot-value obj 'slot) 42)` is invalid. So though I made a mistake back there, you can in fact **indirectly** feed a compound place to `setq`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html) library, which is intended to work on any conforming implementation of Common Lisp, defines `iota`:

```
(iota 5)
=> (0 1 2 3 4)
```

You can also customize start and step:

```
(iota 3 :start 1 :step 1.0)   
=> (1.0 2.0 3.0)
```

But often you do not need to actually produce the list, you just want to iterate over the given range. That's why there is also `map-iota`:

```
(map-iota #'print 3 :start 1 :step 1.0) 
=> 3
```

In such cases you can of course use [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(loop for i from 1.0 below 22 by 1.5 do (print i))
```

Instead of `do`, you can also `collect` and obtain a list; this is a bit more verbose than `iota`, but easier to customize.

Comment: I don't think I can use any library :(

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu Then you can define your own utility function which relies on loop, especially if you don't want to customize start and step.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if can still write mac lisp of the top of my head:

```
(defun foo (num acc)
   (if (eq num 0)
        acc
       (foo (- num 1) (cons num acc))))

(foo 5 nil)
```

should be

```
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: Don't use EQ for numbers, implementations are not required to guarantee that e.g. `(eq 3 (+ 2 1))`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp

Comment: hey i was just enjoying being nostalgic. at least i didn't use rplacd

Comment: I understand being nostalgic, but there are some factual errors in your answer I would rather not see being taught to beginners.

Comment: It works. Just edit it for the reason mentioned. As for beginners, this function foo points out the cleverness of building the list in reverse rather than starting with 1 and having to reverse a list on return, shows a recursive method. Using EQUAL instead of EQ would be nice. Putting in an optional so you could call (foo 5) inseatd of (foo 5 nil) would be nice.