# creating list of ascending numbers in Common Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I just want to make a simple program in c-lisp; take in a number and return a list of all the numbers from 0 to that number. I'm relatively new to lisp and I'm curious how someone more experienced would do it. My program is this:

```
(let ((a 0) (lis '())) 
  (defun counter (len) 
    (setq lis (cons a lis)) (setq a (+ a 1)) 
    (if (< a len) (counter len) lis) 
    ))
```

But I feel like it doesn't quite catch the spirit of lisp, there gotta be more elegant ways right?

Another thought I had was some version of this, but how would you put the output into a list?

```
(defun counter2 (x) 
  (print x) 
  (cond ((< 0 x) (counter2 (- x 1)))))
```

Thank you for your time and eventual help, :)

Comment: Or this one: [LISP - sequence of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131196/lisp-sequence-of-integers)

Comment: CLISP is not the name of the language, which is called Common Lisp or shorter CL. CLISP is a specific implementation of Common Lisp, largely implemented in C.

Comment: What does it mean to put the output into a list? PRINT prints to a text stream. Do you want to collect the printed text? Why?

Answer (score 4):

We'll look at a series of transformations, trying to improve your code:

**Your code:**

```
(let ((a 0) (lis '())) 
  (defun counter (len) 
    (setq lis (cons a lis)) (setq a (+ a 1)) 
    (if (< a len) (counter len) lis) 
    ))
```

**Formatting**

The typical formatting would look like:

```
(let ((a 0)
      (list '())) 
  (defun counter (len) 
    (setq list (cons a list))
    (setq a (+ a 1)) 
    (if (< a len)
        (counter len)
        list)))
```

**Problems**

There are a bunch of problems with above code:

- There is a `LET` surrounding the function definition. This defines the variables `a` and `list` outside of the function? Why?
- it looks very imperative
- it's a recursive function which could run out of stack space
- does not return the list of numbers in ascending order, which was a requirement in your problem statement

**A better recursive version**

Let's look at a recursive version:

```
(defun counter (len &optional (a 0) (list '())) 
  (if (>= a len)
      list
      (counter len
               (1+ a)
               (cons a list))))
```

Above gets rid of the surrounding `LET` and makes the variables `a` and `list` optional parameters.

The base case is also the `then` case in `IF`.

It may be better to hide the variables `a` and `list`. So we can use a local recursive function:

```
(defun counter (len)
  (labels ((counter-rec (a list)
             (if (>= a len)
                 list
               (counter-rec (1+ a) (cons a list)))))
    (counter-rec 0 '())))
```

Above function uses a local function for the recursion.

We still may want to return the list in an ascending order:

```
(defun counter (len)
  (labels ((counter-rec (a list)
             (if (>= a len)
                 list
               (counter-rec (1+ a) (cons a list)))))
    (nreverse
     (counter-rec 0 '()))))
```

Above uses the destructive function `NREVERSE`, which we can use because the generated list is freshly created and not used anywhere else.

We can also count down in the recursive function. This gets rid of the `NREVERSE`:

```
(defun counter (len)
  (labels ((counter-rec (a list)
             (if (minusp a)
                 list
               (counter-rec (1- a) (cons a list)))))
    (counter-rec (1- len) '())))
```

**Using the DO loop for a non-recursive version**

```
(defun counter (len)
  (do* ((a     len  (1- a))
        (list  '()  (cons a list)))
       ((zerop a) list)))

(defun counter (len)
  (do* ((a len (1- a))            ; A from len to zero
        (list '() (cons a list))) ; consing the result
       ((zerop a) list)))         ; the end condition and
                                  ;  list as the result
```

**LOOP**

Common Lisp provides a built-in powerful `LOOP` macro, which let's us write:

```
(defun counter (len)
  (loop for i below len
        collect i))
```

Above iterates `i` from `0` to `(1- len)` and collects each `i` into a list to return.

**COUNTER is called IOTA in Lisp**

A function like `COUNTER` exist in Lisp libraries and is traditionally called `iota`.

```
CL-USER 1 > (ql:quickload "alexandria")
("alexandria")

CL-USER 2 > (apropos "iota")
ALEXANDRIA:MAP-IOTA (defined)
ALEXANDRIA:IOTA (defined)

CL-USER 3 > (ALEXANDRIA:IOTA 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay let's go through this:

```
(let ((a 0) (lis '())) 
  (defun counter (len) 
    (setq lis (cons a lis)) (setq a (+ a 1)) 
    (if (< a len) (counter len) lis) 
    ))
```

There is no reason why the `let` should be outside of the function definition. Put it inside:

```
  (defun counter (len)
    (let ((a 0) (lis '())) 
      (setq lis (cons a lis)) (setq a (+ a 1)) 
      (if (< a len) (counter len) lis) 
    ))
```

Now indent it properly (all closing parens are put at the end.
You don't look at the parens - you just look at the indentation level.
It will tell you how the levels depend on each other.

```
(defun counter (len)
  (let ((a 0) 
        (lis '())) 
    (setq lis (cons a lis)) 
    (setq a (+ a 1)) 
    (if (< a len) 
        (counter len) 
        lis)))
```

You can put the local variables defined in the let to the function's arguments as well. Because they are local variables for the function.
Take them as optional arguments. This eliminates some parantheses.

```
(defun counter (len &optional (a 0) (lis '())) 
    (setq lis (cons a lis)) 
    (setq a (+ a 1)) 
    (if (< a len) 
        (counter len) 
        lis))
```

This prepares the function also for recursion.
Because instead of `setq`-ing `a` and `lis`, you could
call the function itself giving the new values for `a` and `lis`
in a recursive way.
The condition is actually the break condition.
So what we do is to restructure this a little
and use the recursive function call to eliminate the need for `setq`.
By the way - you should rather use `setf`. `setq` is a special case of `setf`. Always use `setf` in common lisp.

```
(defun counter (len &optional (a 0) (lis '()))
    (if (not (< a len))     ;; break condition of the recursion
        lis
        (counter len (+ a 1) (cons a lis)))) ;; this eliminates `setq`s
```

Now comes something what many such recursive functions have in common.
The breaking condition of the recursion if often a question for
emptyness of alist `(null l)` or zero-ness of a number - in our case:
`(zerop len)`.
You pass on `len` but increment `a` from round to round.
You could achieve the same by asking for zero-ness of `len`
and decrease `len` (decrement) from round to round.
So `len` can keep all the info of the rounds - no `a` needed for counting the rounds!

```
(defun counter (len &optional (lis '()))
    (if (zerop len)     ;; typical break condition for recursion!
        lis
        (counter (- len 1) (cons len lis))))
```

I personally like to use `cons` because it shows next to each other
condition and consequent:

```
(defun counter (n &optional (acc '()))
    (cond ((zerop n) (nreverse acc))
          (t (counter (1- n) (cons len acc)))))
```

Also you have to reverse the result. which I call `acc` for `accumulator`.
This is by the way a typical idiom in recursive functions to collect/accumulate using `cons` and then to `reverse` (or for performance reasons to `nreverse`) the `acc`umulator at the end.

Now this last form is the correct form and a very typical recursive function for such matter.

Increment and decrement by 1 is so common - for such kind of recursions, so that common lisp has `1-` and `1+` for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `DOTIMES`

```
(defun counter (len)
  (let ((res ()))
    (dotimes (i (1+ len) (nreverse res))
      (push i res))))
```

or even easier with `LOOP`:

```
(defun counter (len)
  (loop for i from 0 to len collect i))
```